# Как redux'ом заполнить state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

требуется:

- забрать список данных из базы
- отредактировать их на клиенте
- сохранить изменения в базу

данные получаю через redux

```
dispatch(fetch()...
```

но данные попадают в props (которое readOnly)

где и как правильно их передать в state, для последующей возможности их редактировать через setState ?

```
//Component

class myComponent extends Component {
    ...
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        items: state.items
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        onGetItems: () => {
            dispatch(getItems());
        }
    })
)(myComponent);
...
// Middleware
export const getItems = () => dispatch => {

    fetch(url, {
        ...
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS', data: data });
    })  
    .catch(function (error) {  
        console.log('Request failed', error);  
    });
}
...
// Reducer
const initialState = [];

export default function items(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'SUCCESS') {
        return action.data;
    }
  return state;
}
```

`UPDATE`

с бэка приходят данные вида:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ivan",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "fred",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "dima",
        "value": 3
    }
]
```

например мы хотим переименовать `fred` в `stas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе не нужно использовать собственный state компонента для изменения того что лежит в Redux store, ты можешь изменять сам store напрямую через action. Например так:

```
    //Reducer
    export default function employees(state = [], action) {
      if (action.type === 'CHANGE_VALUE') {
         return state.map(person => {
             if(person !== action.id) return Object.assign({}, person);
             return Object.assign({}, person, {
                 [action.field]: action.value
             });
         });
      }
      return state;
    }

    //Action
    const changeFieldValue = (id, field, value) => ({
       type: 'CHANGE_VALUE',
       id,
       field,
       value,
    })

    const Inputs = ({
        inputs,
        onChange,
    }) => (
       <div>
            {inputs.map(input => 
              <input name={input.name} value={input.value} onChange={e => onChange(e)}
            )}
        </div>
    )

    const MyForm = ({
        employees,
        changeFieldValue
    }) => (
        <div>
            {employees.map(employee => 
              <Inputs key={employee.id} 
                      inputs={[
                         { name: 'name', value: empoyee.name },
                         { name: 'value', value: empoyee.value },
                      ]}
                      onChange={(e) => changeFieldValue(employee.id, e.target.name, e.target.value)}
               />
            )}
        </div>
    )

    export default connect(
        (state) => ({
            employees: state.employees
        }),
        {
            changeFieldValue
        }
    )(MyForm);
```

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но Вы показываете пример со скалярным объектом. У меня же требуется получать массивы с бэкенда используя ajax. Представьте, что у Вас таблица записей, и в одной из них надо отредактировать ячейку. Как будет выглядеть Reducer?

Comment: Да, в примере используется скалярный объект, но это не меняет суть ответа, моей задачей было показать вам простенький пример чтобы был понятен сам принцип.
Если вам нужна конкретика, то не могли бы вы привести пример данных которые приходят с сервера, чтобы я лучше мог понять ситуацию и предложить решение.

Comment: добавил данные в вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ с учётом данных

Comment: В ответе я выделил для инпутов отдельный компонент, посмотри - это важно

Comment: спасибо, многое прояснилось

Comment: в каких случаях тогда имеет смысл использовать `state` ?

Comment: Если честно, я сам изучаю и практикую React и Redux не так давно, но для себе сформировал следующее мнение по данному вопросу - state имеет смысл использовать тогда когда ты хочешь манипулировать локальными данными компонента, которые нужны только для этого компонента, ну и может парочке дочерних. Например, в state у компонента MyForm ты можешь хранить свойство fetch, которое ты будешь ставить в true во время сабмита формы, чтобы пользователю показать красивый прелоадер.